# ACH with QuickBooks Desktop - which API?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We've been using the QBMS for our **QB DESKTOP** clients using this QBMS API:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/payments/z_qbms_payments/0060_documentation/transaction_types
This continues to work fine for credit cards, but now we need to support **ACH payments for QB Desktop**. *What API(s) can we use for this?* Note that these QB Desktop clients use a "connection ticket" for authentication.

We also have support for **QB ONLINE** via the new QBO APIs as well as the new QB Payment APIs that does support ACH. This payments API uses OAuth authentication (Access Token Secret) and not the "connection ticket", so is there a way to use this API **in conjunction with QB DESKTOP**? If so, where does the client (*the one that has the Intuit merchant account*) go to obtain the Access Token Secret? Note that the client does not have the QB Online app, they just have a merchant account with Intuit and QBD. So the usual way of going to the Intuit app store and clicking the [Get App Now] button will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ACH payments for QB Desktop. What API(s) can we use for this?

Use the `QuickBooks Payments API`. It's your only choice -- it's the only API Intuit offers which supports ACH. It will do credit cards as well as ACH.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments

> Note that these QB Desktop clients use a "connection ticket" for authentication.

They won't use a connection ticket anymore, they'll use OAuth.

> so is there a way to use this API in conjunction with QB DESKTOP?

Yes.

> If so, where does the client (the one that has the Intuit merchant account) go to obtain the Access Token Secret?

You provide them with a webpage they visit to get the tokens/secrets.

They go through the same OAuth connection process that QuickBooks Online users go through *except* you pass a flag indicating the you only want to connect to `Payments`, and not to `QuickBooks Online`.

Specifically, look at the `datasources.payments` option referred to here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/widgets#/Include_the_JavaScript_library

> Note that the client does not have the QB Online app, they just have a merchant account with Intuit and QBD.

That's just fine. They will NOT need a QuickBooks Online account.

> So the usual way of going to the Intuit app store and clicking the [Get App Now] button will not work.

That's fine, they will NOT be going to the App Store to get connected.

Instead, you'll provide a webpage for them to visit, which kicks off the OAuth flow, and lets them get their OAuth creds.

Comment: We get this: Error Code: no_access_to_this_field
Message: xxx not allowed to get access to QuickBooks
Even though our datasource has this <script type="text/javascript">
                    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
                        grantUrl: 'https://xxx',
                        datasources: {
                            quickbooks : false,
                            payments : true
                        },
                        paymentOptions:{
                            intuitReferred : true
                        }
                    });

    </script>

Comment: Within your Intuit Developer control panel, do you have your app set to allow/use the Payments API as well? If so, I would submit a support ticket to Intuit.

Comment: Interestingly, we had created a new app with just the payment API checked, and this was resulting in the above error. We then went and also enabled the QBO / accounting API and now we are able to go through the OAuth steps. It looks like Intuit is saying you're at least going to have to create a trial QBO account if you want to use our Payment API !!!

Comment: I know we have customers who don't have QBO at all who we have got connected, so it's definitely possible to NOT have QBO and still connect. Your app itself might still need the API checked though.